# qmake subdirs optional target/sub project

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I wondering if there is such a thing like optional targets or sub project in *qmake*, the Qt build tool.

---

**Project**

In my test example I have a subdirs project which contains another two projects, one shared library and one basic application. The application depends on the library which works great. Additionally I have one additional compiler (invoking *lrelease*) and one additional target (invoking *lupdate*), which also works like a charm (the shared library provides them as pri file for multiple projects).

After a complete build in release mode, the Windows deployment tool (namely *windeployqt.exe*) is called and deploys the target with all required shared libraries and plugins to my deployment directory.

Last component I wish to add is the creation of an installer using the **Qt Installer Framework**, which in fact should be easily done one the executables are located. Thus I want to create another sub project which contains all the installer stuff and provides the *qmake* steps to create one. But the project should not be build all the time but only when I want to, preferably over the create menu of *Qt Creator*.

**Question**

Is there any way to make a *qmake* subdirs sub project fully optional, so it will not be built using the default build all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *qmake* documentation states that one should use the test function [*requires(condition)*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#requires-condition) to skip building a whole project. Using this one may add a new build configuration, namely bundle as example, which defines a configuration variable as @Jeffrey pointed out in his answer.

I managed to get it working with the following *qmake* project definition:

```
requires(BUNDLE_INSTALLER)

TEMPLATE = aux

QMAKE_POST_LINK = ...
```

Once you define the variable, over a new build configuration for proper working with Qt Creator (example), the steps listed under *QMAKE_POST_LINK* are performed. So I may bundle the installer, if I want to.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a check around it:

```
enableOptional {
    message(optional enabled)
    SUBDIRS += YourSubDir
}
```

And call `qmake` with

```
qmake CONFIG+=enableOptional yourProject.pro
```

Comment: That might be an option but then I only see the project in Qt Creator when the variable is defined. I also do not see any possibility of moving this condition, like to the project file itself, so that the resulting target can be compfortably build using the Qt Create menu options under build... but nice catch.

Comment: One of the reasons why I moved from the QtCreator to vim, as I used this trick fairly heavily in the project.

Comment: Just a note - if you add YourSubDirProject by default, but remove it like: `if disabled {
    message(optional disabled)
    SUBDIRS -= YourSubDir
}` - it will be still present in Qt Creator, but will not be build.